# I can not take a value from the header in the Controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-headers, response-headers

I have built a web application in Spring Boot that has a form and besides the values from the form that it inserts in the database it takes from the header the username. This is the code from the Controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/BilantErr/")
public String postIndex(@RequestParam(name = "cui") String cui, @RequestParam(name = "an_raportare") String anRaportare,
    @RequestParam(name = "perioada") String perioada,
    @RequestHeader("iv-user") String operator, @RequestParam(name = "motivatie") String motivatie, Model model) {

    String page = "";
    //String operator = "serban";
    try {
        if (repository.insert(cui, anRaportare, operator, motivatie, perioada) == true) {
            page = "success";
        } else {
            page = "error";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BilantErr.class);
    }
    return page;
}
```

The error that I am getting is : `Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'iv-user' for method parameter type String is not present]`

What may be the problem ? There is an application already built in JSF that works and takes the user from the header and I have to replace it with a Spring app. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the header is being sent by the client in the first place? That is, have you *checked* or are you just *assuming* that it's being sent?

Answer (score 1):

`MissingRequestHeaderException` means the HTTP request doesn't contain a "iv-user" header. You must have a look to your request first. You can read all headers of the HTTP request by following code snippet:

```java
@GetMapping("/listHeaders")
public ResponseEntity<String> multiValue(
  @RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
    headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
        LOG.info(String.format(
          "Header '%s' = %s", key, value.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|"))));
    });
        
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(
      String.format("Listed %d headers", headers.size()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request header "iv-user" is required but does not seem to be present in the request you receive. You could fix your request or make the header optional: `@RequestHeader(value = "iv-user", required = false)`